# how to filter in R based off specific key words and use in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a csv file that contains movie names, budgets, profit, and genre. There are 15 genres, but I want to plot the budgets of only 5 of the genres which are action, adventure, comedy, drama and animation. how do I filter for movies that fall in these genres?

Comment: You could use `filter` from `dplyr` in the data you pass to ggplot. If you need more concrete help than that, I'm afraid we need a more concrete example. Please post your data (or at least a sample of it), and the code you are using for your plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter 5 genres using `filter` from `dplyr`,

```
target_genres <- c( 'action', 'adventure', 'comedy', 'drama', 'animation')
filtered <- df %>% filter(genres %in% target_genres)
```